# Not able to save data using Django form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I stack. I try many thinks. I want to put 2 forms in my mainpage. Models, forms in index.html, ModelForm, save(), urls.. I think everything ok. But submit button do nothing.

```
#models.py
from django.db import models

class Iletisim(models.Model):
    DURUM = [
        ('KT', 'Keşif Talebi'),
        ('AB', 'Arıza Bildirimi'),
        ('IL', 'İletişimden'),
    ]
    SINIF = [
        ('Konut', (
            ('SI', 'Site '),
            ('DA', 'Apartman Dairesi'),
            ('VI', 'Yazlık/Bağ/Villa'),
        )
         ),
        ('İşyeri', (
            ('OF', 'Ofis/Büro/Dükkan'),
            ('FA', 'Fabrika/Şantiye/Otel/Okul'),
        )
         ),
        ('DG', 'Diğer'),
    ]
    name    = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Ad/Soyad")
    phone   = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Telefon")
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name="Adresi")
    message = models.CharField(max_length=1000, verbose_name="Mesaj")
    email   = models.EmailField(max_length=40, verbose_name="E-Posta")
    province= models.CharField(max_length=40,verbose_name="Şehir")
    tarih   = models.DateTimeField(default=None)
    basvuru = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=DURUM)
    sinif   = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=SINIF)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["tarih", "email"]
        verbose_name = "Mesaj"
        verbose_name_plural = "Mesajlar"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.basvuru
```

My forms folder

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.forms import ModelForm
from apps.giris.models import Iletisim

class Kesif_Form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Iletisim
        fields = '__all__'


def kesif_kayit(request):

    if request.method=='POST':
        form = Kesif_Form(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            yeni_kesif      = Iletisim()
            yeni_kesif.name = request.POST.get("name")
            yeni_kesif.phone = request.POST.get("phone")
            yeni_kesif.address = request.POST.get("address")
            yeni_kesif.message = request.POST.get("message")
            yeni_kesif.email = request.POST.get("email")
            yeni_kesif.province = request.POST.get("province")
            yeni_kesif.tarih = request.POST.get("tarih")
            yeni_kesif.basvuru = request.POST.get("basvuru")
            yeni_kesif.sinif = request.POST.get("sinif")

            yeni_kesif.save()
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = Kesif_Form()

    context={'form' : form}
    return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

Main class

```
...
from forms.formlar import Kesif_Form

class Anasayfa_View(TemplateView, Kesif_Form):
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    ...
        context['kform']        = Kesif_Form
    ...
        return context
```

index.html

```
...
{{ kform.errors }}
<form action="{% url 'kesif' %}" method="POST" class="php-email-form php-email-form animate__animated animate__fadeInRight">

    {{ kform.errors }}
    {{ kform }}
    <input type="submit" value="gir">
</form>
...
```

urls.py

```
...
from forms.formlar import kesif_kayit

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', Anasayfa_View.as_view(), name='grsndx'),
    path('kesif/', kesif_kayit, name='kesif'),
    path('<str:ktgr>/', Detaylar_View.as_view(), name='dtyndx'),
    path('<str:ktgr>/<str:bslk>/', Detay_View.as_view(), name='dtydty'),
]
```

and submit not work, every fields in form, I want 2 forms but I have not work anyone.
help..

structure

```
-project
  -apps
    -giris
       -models.py
    +detay
    ...
  +env
  -fls
     -settings
     -urls
  -forms
     -formlar.py
     ...
  -templates
     -index.html
     ...
  -manage.py
  ...
```

Comment: I allowed me to remove js in the form class section of the template I was using.
The js redirects in the templates are blocking everything.
The records to the database are working fine. It is announced to those who will experience the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Django model form than you have to do something like this first create form class

```
class Kesif_Form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Iletisim
        fields = '__all__'#here you to defined specific you field or all the field
```

than you have to submit it like this

```
def kesif_kayit(request):

    if request.method=='POST':
        form = Kesif_Form(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = Kesif_Form()

    context={'form' : form}
    return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

you don't have save it manually `Django Model Form` will save it for you.

Comment: thanks I remove save. How about url directive

Comment: I din't get what you are trying to say in which part you have problem.

Comment: The forms I am trying to create do nothing when I press the register button. I removed the registration process as you said. Do I need to make any changes to the urls.py file? I did not make any changes to the view I created for the homepage. only models.py file has my Contact field, forms.py has ModelForm which includes all fields and form in index.py. are these enough for django to record?

Comment: No, you don't have to change your URL .

Comment: I had to remove the redirect in urls.py because I removed save.

Comment: so check that your data is saved or not in database

Comment: I've written so much code, I don't know how bored I am. There are no records in the database or in the admin. The registration button of the form does nothing. It doesn't give an error either. It doesn't do anything even though I have kform.errors on my form.

Comment: What should I enter in the action field in the form?

Comment: okay i found after you pointed me about for action you have to put `grsndx` instead of `kesif`

Comment: wait i will send you request

Comment: Try to add this inside your `Anasayfa_View` `def form_valid(self, form):
        return super().form_valid(form)`

Comment: https://www.agiliq.com/blog/2019/01/django-createview/#:~:text=Django%20provides%20several%20class%20based,submission%20of%20a%20valid%20form.